# TextView doesn't fit in one line in some devices and small in others

Tags: android, textview

I got a problem in the TextView: by using textSize 36sp the text is show clear in some medium devices and big in small devices and small in big devices. What's the solution?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/android_back"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="@string/from"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="36sp" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'the text is show clear'?

Comment: i mean to fit on multiscreen